# How do I overload cout for my object?

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I have a this struct:

```
struct DigitNode{
  char digit;
  DigitNode *prev;
  DigitNode *next; 
};
```

My BigInt class has private member variables: Bigint *head and Bigint *tail.

What I am trying to do is implement a BigInt datatype. My struct is a doubly linked list with each node containing a digit of a number. The number it should represent is the number you would get from the linked list if you read each character left to right.

This is my constructor:

```
BigInt::BigInt(const string &numIn) throw(BigException)
{  

  DigitNode *ptr = new DigitNode;
  DigitNode *temp;
  ptr->prev = NULL;
  if (numIn[0] == '-' || numIn[0] == '+') ptr->digit = numIn[0];
  else ptr->digit = numIn[0] - '0';
  this->head = ptr;
  for (int i = 1; numIn[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
      ptr->next = new DigitNode;
      temp = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->next;
      ptr->digit = numIn[i] - '0';
      ptr->prev = temp;
    }
  ptr->next = NULL;
  this->tail = ptr;

}
```

This is my attempt at an operator<< overloader:

```
ostream&  operator<<(ostream & stream, const BigInt & bigint)
{ 

  DigitNode *ptr = bigint.head;
  string num = "";
  while (ptr != NULL)
    {
      num += ptr->digit;
    }

  return  stream << num; 
}
```

This is my error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Thank you! I added it, now the problem is it outputs nothing.

Comment: dont use throw declarations - they are useless and deprecated

Comment: For future reference it's bad form to edit your question to address a _completely different problem_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your `while` loop the `ptr` variable never contains `NULL`. This causes an endless loop that exhausts all of your memory while it builds the string. To fix this you need to advance `ptr` to the next linked element. The second problem is that you are storing *values* 0 through 9 in `digit` instead of actual their respective characters representations. You need to adjust the value when you append it to the string, like so.

```
while (ptr != NULL)
{
    num += ptr->digit + '0';
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```